# Makes changes to asound.conf effective without restarting services?

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, alsa

I am running a mopidy based spotify player on a raspberry pi  - my goal is to utilise both the onboard analog audio as well as an external USB sound card, with a different set of speakers in different rooms plugged into each, creating a multi room system.

The key is to be able to switch / redirect audio on the fly ie without rebooting, stopping music.

This is the closest I have gotten:

sudo nano /etc/asound.conf

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

change card from 0 (onboard analog) to 1 (external usb)

then

```
killall -9 mopidy

/opt/startmopidy.sh
```

This does the job but killing mopidy stops the music (and editing asound.conf doesn't have a high WAF!) but i cant get the setting to take effect without reloading mopidy.

Someone suggested I try Pulse Audio instead of ALSA but before I do want to see if I can find a method using ALSA....suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

ALSA does not allow changing the hardware device without actually opening the other device, which would require support by the application.

You need PulseAudio for that.